# delete [] p; fails to return control to the application.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I encountered an odd situation where a destructor

```
pointer_holder::~pointer_holder(){
     delete [] pointer;
}
```

Made the application unresponsive; the system call never returned to the process. 
No error, nothing.

My debugging traced it to the destructor call. The step-into/step-over froze the debugger on that statement. The debugger was still responsive. The pointer value was a reasonable one. The pointer value was previously recorded as returned by a `:pointer(new int[N])` constructor initialization by that same object.

What can prompt this odd and unreasonable behavior by delete?

Comment: I've had that happen when I wrote outside the array bounds and messed up bookkeeping info.

Comment: @JamesRoot Interesting. In this case I kept an extremely close eye on the arrays involved. The execution up to this point consisted of three new[]s and this is the second delete[], on very small arrays < 4 elements.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When undefined behaviour has been triggered, anything can happen.

Comment: Did you violate the Rule of Five?

Comment: @M.M I might have triggered UB, I don't think so. But even in UB territory this is odd behavior by delete.

Comment: @KerrekSB The five was involved, my careful debugging told me nothing was afowl.